# Way to check if a ZIP file is empty?

Tags: java, zip

I'm using a pre-built method that returns an object of type File. It's known that the file I'm receiving is a zip of a directory. What's the quickest way I could check if it's empty i.e. has no files? Do i need to necessarily extract it?

EDIT: I think I may have ambiguously worded the title. My requirement is to check that the number of entries in the zipped directory are zero. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Open it as a `ZipFile` and see, by iteration, whether it has any `ZipEntry` objects in it that have non-zero length.

Comment: @user207421 Why non-zero length? If a zip file has an empty file, the zip file itself isn't empty.

Comment: @Andreas Depends entirely on what the OP requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check is a zip file is empty:

```
boolean isEmpty;
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file)) {
    isEmpty = (zipFile.size() == 0);
}
```

Comment: @user207421 This code is not checking if the zip file itself has a size of 0. It checks if the number of zip entries is 0. Javadoc of `ZipFile.size()`: *Returns the **number of entries** in the ZIP file.* --- To check file size, the code would be `file.length() == 0`, and that's not what this code is doing. That would actually be an invalid zip file.