# Check if zip is empty in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question. I'm trying to find out if my file which is a .zip is empty.
The problem is that testing the length does not work because the size of a zip file is never equal to 0.

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = ...
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
{                    
    if (fileInfo.Length < 0)
    {
       //  do action like delete
    }                                 
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Don't work because fileInfo.lenght is never == 0. This is why I search for a solution to known if zip is empty

Comment: Here is a related post, it's in Java but it may assist you https://stackoverflow.com/q/60880995/12282360

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.open?view=net-6.0) functionality:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
  int fileCount = archive.Entries.Count;
  bool isEmpty = fileCount == 0;
}
```